# Shading in Region of a Circle

Tags: tikz

I am trying to shade in the wedge of this circle that is swept out by the angle:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,line width=1pt]
\begin{axis}[
color= white,
xmin=-1.5, 
xmax=1.5, 
ymin=-1.5, 
ymax=1.5, 
axis equal image, 
axis lines=middle, 
xticklabels={}, 
yticklabels={},
font=\scriptsize,
ticks=none,
xlabel = $x(t)$,
ylabel = $y(t)$,
inner axis line style={stealth-stealth}
]

\draw[black] (0,0) circle [radius=1];

\draw[<->]
    (1,0) coordinate (a) %node[right] {}
    -- (0,0) coordinate (b) %node[left] {b}
    -- (0.3,0.953939) coordinate (c) %node[above right] {c}
    pic[draw=orange, <->, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=1cm]
    {angle=a--b--c};

\draw[black, ->] coordinate (a) (0,0) -- (1,0);

\draw[black, ->] coordinate (b) (0,0) -- (0.3,0.953939);

\node[black, left, scale=1] at (0.3, 0.17) {$\theta$};



\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I have tried using `\draw[] arc` but that has been confusing, and I am sure that there has to be a more efficient way, such as defining paths and shading within the reason?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **`opacity` parameter** for components of that part of the drawing:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,line width=1pt]
  \begin{axis}[
    color= white,
    xmin=-1.5, 
    xmax=1.5, 
    ymin=-1.5, 
    ymax=1.5, 
    axis equal image, 
    axis lines=middle, 
    xticklabels={}, 
    yticklabels={},
    font=\scriptsize,
    ticks=none,
    xlabel = $x(t)$,
    ylabel = $y(t)$,
    inner axis line style={stealth-stealth}
  ]
    \draw[black] (0,0) circle [radius=1];
    \draw[<->,opacity=0.5]
        (1,0) coordinate (a) %node[right] {}
        -- (0,0) coordinate (b) %node[left] {b}
        -- (0.3,0.953939) coordinate (c) %node[above right] {c}
        pic[draw=orange, <->, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=1cm]
        {angle=a--b--c};
    \draw[black, ->, opacity=0.5] coordinate (a) (0,0) -- (1,0);
    \draw[black, ->, opacity=0.5] coordinate (b) (0,0) -- (0.3,0.953939);
    \node[black, left, scale=1, opacity=0.5] at (0.3, 0.17) {$\theta$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]